# xcode 5 removing ipad launch images when adding additional sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

So I have an app and since version 5.0 of Xcode came out I have been trying to get the launch screen images updated. Unfortunately when I try to add either the :

Portrait Retina, Landscape Non Retina, or Landscape Retina it removes whichever one is next to it.

So I will go to add The landscape Retina and the image will appear. However when I go to add the landscape non-retina the Landscape retina image will not longer be referenced. 
[image]

After adding Non-retina:

[image]

Is there a way to double check or add the images without dealing with the interface? Am I doing something wrong? Is it because I haven't added the 1536x2048 yet?

Comment: your iamge have a correct size?

Comment: Yes they do, it continually tries to force the non correct image in and makes tons of duplicates in the plist